# mostly finished reddit crawler is failing to crawl more than 9 or so pages

Tags: java, web-crawler, reddit

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Scraper {
    private String filePath = "c://reddit//";
    private String url;
    private int count;
    private String after;
    private static String subreddit;

    public Scraper(String sr) {
        url = String.format("http://www.reddit.com/r/%s.xml?limit=100", sr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter subreddit with pics only");
        subreddit = input.next();
        System.out.println("enter amount of pages to crawl");
        int pages = input.nextInt();
        Scraper scraper = new Scraper(subreddit);
        input.close();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < pages) {
            scraper.getNextPage();
            scraper.getImgur();
            scraper.getImgurA();
            scraper.getImgurAddI();
            i++;
        }

    }

    public void download(String _url, String name) {
        /*
         * setup streams.. write image as bytes to filePath
         */
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(_url);
            is = url.openStream();
            os = new FileOutputStream(filePath + name + ".jpg");
            for (int b; (b = is.read()) != -1;) {
                os.write(b);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            System.out.println("invalid url");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("no stream");
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void getImgur() {
        /*
         * grab all imgur's in the context of http://i.imgur.com/. The second
         * parameter to download() is the filename
         */
        try {
            System.out.println("connecting to imgur");
            Elements description = getSubreddit();
            for (Element imgur : description) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern
                        .compile("http://i\\.imgur\\.com/\\w+");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(imgur.text());
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println("downloading image: " + " "
                            + matcher.group());
                    download((matcher.group() + ".jpg"), matcher.group()
                            .substring(18));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("getImgur() failed");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("grabbed all imgurs");
        }

    }

    public void getImgurAddI() {
        /*
         * grab all imgur's in the context of http://imgur.com/, if it is an
         * album then skip otherwise add "i" to beginning of imgur in order to
         * get image
         */
        try {
            System.out.println("finding imgurs without prefix i and adding i");
            Elements description = getSubreddit();
            for (Element imgur : description) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://imgur\\.com/\\w+");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(imgur.text());
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    if (!matcher.group().endsWith("a")) {
                        // make imgur downloadable by adding 'i' before imgur
                        String newUrl = matcher.group();
                        newUrl = "http://i." + newUrl.substring(7);
                        download(newUrl + ".jpg", newUrl.substring(18));
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("getImgurAddI() failed");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("grabbed all imgurs by adding I");
        }

    }

    private void getImgurA() {
        /*
         * grab all albums then call extract() to get each individual image
         */
        try {
            System.out.println("connecting to imgur album");
            Elements description = getSubreddit();
            for (Element imgur : description) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://imgur.com/a/\\w+");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(imgur.text());
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println("Downloading image album...." + " "
                            + matcher.group());
                    extract(matcher.group());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("getImgurA() failed");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("extracted all imgur albums");
        }
    }

    private void extract(String album) {
        /*
         * open connection to imgur album and download each individual image,
         * validate imgur..if it ends with "s" most likely a thumbnail duplicate
         * so skip it
         */
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(album).get();
            Elements pics = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
            String image = null;
            for (Element pic : pics) {
                /*
                 * get all image's inside the data-src attribute, make sure url
                 * is valid first
                 */
                image = pic.attr("data-src");
                if (image != ""
                        && (!image.substring(0, image.length() - 4).endsWith(
                                "s"))) {
                    if (image.endsWith(".jpg?1") || image.endsWith(".jpg?2")) {
                        if (image.substring(2, image.length() - 6)
                                .endsWith("s")) {
                            System.out
                                    .println("skipping download of thumbnail/duplicate");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("extracting jpg1/jpg2..... "
                                    + image.substring(2));
                            download(
                                    "http://"
                                            + image.substring(2,
                                                    image.length() - 2),
                                    image.substring(14, image.length() - 6));
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("extracting..... "
                                + image.substring(2));
                        download("http://" + image.substring(2),
                                image.substring(14));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("extract() failed");
        }

    }

    public Elements getSubreddit() {
        /*
         * return an Elements with the information to be scraped
         *  to caller method, setup user agent
         */
        Document doc;
        Elements description = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .userAgent(
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
            description = doc.getElementsByTag("description");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("getSubreddit() failed");
        }
        return description;
    }

    public void getNextPage() {
        /*
         * crawls current url to get next url
         */
        System.out.println("Crawling next page..............");
        Document doc;
        try {
            url = url.replace(".xml", "");
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements next = doc.getElementsByTag("span");
            for (Element n : next) {
                if (n.className().equals("nextprev")) {
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("after=\\w+");
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(n.toString());
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                        after = matcher.group().substring(6);
                        count += 100;
                        url = String
                                .format("http://www.reddit.com/r/%s.xml?limit=100&count=%d&after=%s",
                                        subreddit, count, after);
                        System.out.println("Crawling page.........: " + url);

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("getNextPage() failed");

        }
    }
}
```

Sorry this is probably hard to read I have not broken it up yet because I am still working out the kinks. It seems to crawl 9 pages without a single error than every page after that just fails, the issue is "socket timed out" or "connection timed out". Here is an example output of trying to crawl 25 pages `http://pastebin.com/sP9UwGk9`. The bigger issue is that I had it actually be a multi threaded crawler, but it failed 50x more so I made it slower. I added in bunch of Thread.sleep every time the website connected or started a download but I still kept getting errors. Is there something I am doing wrong? I know reddit has some type of limiter but I am not sure whats wrong because this program is pretty slow in the first place(unless I use the threads).

edit: console log
http://pastebin.com/fhrjSeKx

Comment: Work out the kinks and then ask about a specific problem.

Comment: When I said kinks I meant fix the timeout issue, but I am not sure what is causing it. The error log shows that it downloads fine for a while, but towards the end every one fails.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What URL is it failing on?

Comment: ill brb with a new error log with this information

Comment: Have you tried skipping the first 8 pages and starting processing with the 9th? It's entirely possible that reddit is detecting the large number of requests you are hitting it with and shutting you down.

Comment: ^no I have not but I have tried slowing down my downloads. I am just not sure how to avoid doing too large of a request, I already put a thread.sleep(2000) in every method for every image it finds, and it still failed. I removed it and it worked fine so its kind of random/iffy. Look at my edit for new console log.

Comment: well I just realized its because there is nothing after 9 pages >< damn. There is still a timeout error in there on line 688 though that I need to consider, because when I turn it into multi threaded it gets a lot more of those errors

Comment: When writing automation tools it's always a good idea to check what happens when you do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Most reddit listings only go back approximately 1000 items. Since your `limit` parameter is set to `100`, you're reaching the end of the listing after 10 pages, which is why you're not getting any additional data.

If you need additional items from the subreddit, you may need to pull in data from other listings or the [search API](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_search)